# Jira Agile: Claim story points at a stage other than closed/done

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I have a scrum process in place for my team and i want to make a little change in the JIRA Agile plugin. I have four columns:

1. Open/Todo
2. In Progress
3. Resolved/In UAT
4. Closed/Done

when I place a story in closed column the burndown chart shows the claimed story point and the graph goes down. What I want to do is change that and make JIRA claim the story points as soon as I have put a story into Resolved column. This is because my definition of "done" is once the developer has finished working on a story and has performed unit testing we will call that story "done".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum definition of done should be working software. You can't have working software unless it has been tested.

"The heart of Scrum is a Sprint, a time-box of one month or less during which a “Done”, useable, and potentially releasable product Increment is created." - Scrum Guide on Sprints

If you dont have working software at the end of the sprint then you dont have transparency, and you can't inspect and adapt. In short your development process can't be Empirical.

Without an empirical process you will not be building the right software, you will have excessive rework (as QA finds issues) and you are wasting your Product Owners money.

Comment: I think you didnt get my question, what I asked is say we have a functionality A and we have developed it, unit tested, QA tested, UAT tested, not its ready to be shipped, but its business decision to ship it or not but this is the point where I want to claim the story points. "Resolved/In UAT" column name is a bit misleading because it actually mean it has passed all the testing.

Comment: Then mark it as DONE and use a different process to manage the bits after Done...

Answer (score 0):

JIRA thinks something is 'done' when there is a value in the resolution field. It doesn't actually care what the status is called.

Typically, there will be a resolution screen popped up when you transition an issue to Closed/Done. When you give the issue a resolution then JIRA counts it towards the burndown and also puts a line through the item in the backlog.

Now there is nothing to stop you modifying the workflow so that a resolution is added at an earlier status (e.g. Resolved/In UAT).

You do this by associating the transition from In Progress to Resolved/In UAT with the resolution screen. You would probably also take off the resolution screen from the transition from Resolved/In UAT to Closed/Done.